# Почему не работает настройка в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Почему-то не работает настройка в .htaccess

если заходить так http://site.ru/profile/personal - работает, а если так в подраздел http://site.ru/profile/personal/changepass не работает просто пустая страница без ошибок

```
############################################################################
#### Профайл                                                            ####
############################################################################

RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ profile.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/([a-zA-Z_-]+)$ profile.php?p=$1&s=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ profile.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/?$ profile.php?p=$1&s=$2 [L]
```

Но вообще лучше переходить на что-то вроде:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php
```

а разбором строки запроса уже заниматься в своих скриптах

Comment: что-то не заработало

Comment: А что у вас вообще в htaccess есть кроме этих строк ?

Comment: да много всего... главное вот такие конструкции работают RewriteRule ^([0-9_]+)/deals/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ /deals.php?id_cabinet=$1&p=deals&s=$2 [L]

Comment: Вероятнее всего какое-то другое правило перебивает то, что вы хотите чтобы сработало

Comment: да, так и есть! Уже методом тыка сделал.... Поставил правило выше всех...